# How do you practice soccer effectively alone?

Tags: football, training

I'm 15 and I want to practice soccer. So I searched for training projects and I've found 2 of them. But I don't have any friends at home, only at school. I've tried to go to those projects alone but I returned back, I don't know why, probably scared.

So my only chance is to practice by myself. How can I practice soccer with just a ball, no equipments?

Comment: Where do you live? No football clubs with youth teams in your vicinity? Practicing football on your own is very difficult. You might be able to pass/kick a ball perfectly where you want it, etc. But if you've got no idea where to run on a pitch/what to do in a game that serves to nothing in the end. If no other oppurtunities are availble, I'd say put up and finish one of those training projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Medicine ball** such as 3kg for an adult and 1-2kg for adolescent is an awesome investment to improve your balance, patience and leg-eye coordination technique. Learn to balance on top of the medicine ball to work on your core, vital to fast turns and more advanced shots in soccer. Learn to keep the medicine ball on your leg and then proceed to real ball -- it is extremely motivating to see how fast you develop your technique!

If you cannot afford medicine ball, put a rock inside a styrofoam or tape and do your ball with some weight. Also experiment with some physics and put the weights on the exterior of the styrofoam and you realise that you are able to get a ball of similar properties as earlier with the weight in the middle but less weight.

My favourite thing while training alone is to use Medicine balls. You can use them for weight training, for technique, for massage, for anything creative -- go to a silent basement and learn to stand on top of medicine ball while getting support from the wall is one of the wow effect: little by little you learn new things and suddenly you realise how awesome you are getting in your technique proceeding from your basement to the fields.

*Motivate yourself with awesome things such as*

1. Freestyle Football: a lot of technique training, youtube with a lot of videos such as [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PsX2SzRP4k)
2. Balls of different weight: developing coordination and balance is easier with heavier balls because mass has its slowness, more mass so more force needed to adjust the ball -- my favourite are Medicine Balls such as 1,2,3,4 kg
3. Balls of different sizes

**The good thing in medicine ball is that they are timeless.**

Whatever your age, you can find them. You can find medicine balls of different weights and they don't get old. 1kg ball is awesome after an intensive game to relax your muscles. 1kg ball is equally awesome for a kid to feel his/her muscles better in his/her legs. If a child is not ready for 1kg ball, have an orange in a picnic or play some other round thing on April's fools day with your children.

Improving ligaments and joints early can safely be done in many other ways. The ways contain gymnastic, yoga, skateboarding, surfing, horse riding, dancing as well as balancing with medicine balls. Choose a method you like most and combine freely together as you wish. And remember to drink a lot of water so your joints, ligaments and bones are more resilient and no injuries in trying new things. Have fun.

Comment: Yeah, agree but i don't think I'm just gonna go to the field and just start running and shooting to an empty net. Should I just go to the project or do what I mentioned above?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the projects? You need to balance your efforts working alone with working socially, only way to get to the top is to make things progressively harder, quality is the key: playing against just one player can revolutinize your skills or open eyes to key weaknesses. Instead of shooting to a net, you can shoot to a wall where you have faster rebounds and more shots. Can you find a wall on which you can practise alone?

Comment: OK well, "projects", in our country, are trainings of soccer with coaches and many balls. The projects have 4 levels; A, B, C and D. Level D is for beginners and A is for adult pros which probably will be chosen by a team to play in. I've joined the project once with a friend, for few days but I thought it as very tiring and a waste of time (the project starts in the early morning). And yes i can get that kinda wall.

Comment: I would recommend to test different projects -- if you can find someone like mentor who has got best level, I would ask him/her to guide you. There can be big quality differences between projects. In [Finland](https://fi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suomen_jalkapallon_sarjaj%C3%A4rjestelm%C3%A4), projects sound like divisions (From 1st, best, to lower). When I was your age, I got from 3rd division to the first division (playing in one year older group) and the intensity of the training, games, finance become just harder and harder. In 1st, perfect technique crucial to save energy, bones, joints...

Comment: @BenJunior It takes time to get used to high intensity training, not necessarily the best time to enter. Interval training is usually practised during winter season when no games while high intensity training during game season. When you feel tired, enough proper nutrition is crucial -- if you feel tired when you wake up, it can be due to low iron or low ferritin storages. Feel free to ask more specific questions about being tired after football training -- it can have many reasons.

Comment: And I have another case. There's a field in our neighborhood. I go there with a hope of somebody is there that I can play. I sometimes find some people a little older and much more skilled than me. One time, I played with them and scored an amazing goal from a distance. I play well at home. But at school, during, PE sessions, I could barely touch the ball(literally). I don't know if it is nervousness or anything(I feel a little nervous even if this is the third year in this school). And BTW I have a friend that is probably the top player from 9th grade, he'll probably be my mentor.

Comment: @BenJunior variety of balls can be an issue, reason why you feel like not in touch when in school: the school balls can be old and over-used. Even though balls can be the same, age of the ball can matter or a reason you don't know, girls, peer-pressure? When I was in school for PE and I was not in touch, I relaxed and did warm-up instead -- you have good days and bad days, let it be like that. Make sure the next day is better than the one at a point. People may smirk at you and pressure you to be, new Ronald -- ignore them. Listen to yourself, your body, act diligently, focus on real training.

Comment: I suspect one thing to be a factor and it's that I don't get the ball that much. My teammates don't pass to me(b/c I can't play), and the other team which has the best players from our section. One time I got in to a team with my friend, the mentor, and made an assist for a great header.

Comment: @BenJunior Dominance is an important thing in football that is hard to measure, a bit like dominance in chess. If player passes a ball, s/he does not want it to get lost and the goal is to score. A good player is able to predict 2-5 shots ahead. Please do not feel afraid to ask new questions.